# Moments of a Ratio distribution (Normal variable / Non-central chi variable)

Tags: normal-distribution, t-distribution, chi-distribution

Let $[x_1, x_2, x_3]$ are three independent points in Cartesian space which are Gaussian distributed with a non-zero mean and identity covariance.

I need to calculate the following expectations,

\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}\left[ \frac{x_i}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}}\right],\quad \mathrm{E}\left[ \frac{x_i^2}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}}\right],\quad \mathrm{E}\left[ \frac{x_ix_j}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}}\right]
\end{align}

I know the denominator is a non-central $\chi$-distributed variable with three degrees of freedom. But couldn't solve by plugging in the pdfs. I think the individual ratios should be non-central T distributed but how to get the values is the problem !

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The sum of the squares is not Chisquared (as the title suggests):  given non-zero means, the sum of squares is non-central Chisquared (and presumably not independent of the numerator).

Comment: @wolfies, You are right, it's non-central Chi distribution. Also, the denominator and numerator are dependent.

Comment: It's not what you are asking for, because the denominators in my problem are chi-squared, not chi, but maybe the pointers mentioned in this other answer can be a useful starting point to look for references or approximations https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/605559/expected-value-of-the-outer-product-of-normalized-non-centered-gaussian-vector